# explanation to this recursion problem in python

Tags: python, oop, recursion, backtracking, object-oriented-analysis

check this sample code for backtracking, there are two ways I can append the variable `i` to `curr` before backtracking, the one here (not commented) updates the global `ans` array, whereas the other way doesn't (shown below).:

```
n = 4
k = 2
ans = []
def backtrack(first, curr):
    if len(curr)==k:
        ans.append(curr)
    for i in range(first, n+1):
        # curr.append(i)
        backtrack(i+1, curr+[i])
        # curr.pop()

curr = []
backtrack(1, curr)
print("result = ",ans)
```

output here: `result = [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]`

for the other way:

```
n = 4
k = 2
ans = []
def backtrack(first, curr):
    if len(curr)==k:
        ans.append(curr)
    for i in range(first, n+1):
        curr.append(i)
        backtrack(i+1, curr)
        curr.pop()

curr = []
backtrack(1, curr)
print("result = ",ans)
```

output here:  `result = [[], [], [], [], [], []]`

I wish to understand, what exactly changes here and why the global output array `ans` behaves differently

Comment: Please create a complete [mre] with 2 complete functions and the results you get...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: just did, thanks for the tip @julien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`curr+[i]` creates a new object which gets passed to the next recursive call. So whenever you then append `curr` to `ans` with this version, you append a new object showing you a snapshot of what `curr` is which won't later get modified.

When you instead use `.append` and `.pop`, you keep passing and having only one single object, so when you append it to `ans` it is really that unique object that you append everytime again and again. Then you will keep updating that unique object which will reflect on all element of `ans` since they are the same object. Given at the end of processing `curr` gets cleared you end up having only empty lists everywhere, even if at every step `curr` had actually the value you wanted.

You can see that by adding this print first to check that apart from this bug, everything still works the same in both cases as you would expect:

```
def backtrack(first, curr):
    print(first, id(curr), curr)
    # ... and the rest
```

To fix the second version, you can pass a copy instead:

```
curr.append(i)
backtrack(i+1, curr.copy())
curr.pop()
```

or copy when you append to `ans`

```
ans.append(curr.copy())
```